# In GD Looking for a way to increase total image size while having image preserved as same size

Tags: php, image, gd

So I need have an image uploaded with a background. I would like the actual image to stay approximately 120px in the middle of a black background of 168px as a 12px border.
So far I wrote this with php/GD, but it doesn't quite give me the effect I needed:

```
    
    
    //set the dimensions for the pinkynail
    $pinky_width = $width*0.72;
    $pinky_height = $height*0.72;
    $pinky_borderw = $width*0.14;
    $pinky_borderh = $height*0.14;

    //create the pinkynail
    $pinky = imagecreatetruecolor($pinky_width, $pinky_height);
    imagecopyresampled($pinky, $image, $pinky_borderw, $pinky_borderh, 0, 0, $pinky_width, $pinky_height,
        $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($pinky, $pinkydir . '/' . $image_id . '.jpg', 100);
    imagedestroy($pinky);
```

Am I even on the right track?

I was expecting a border all around the image, but it cuts off the bottom right and shifts it left and from the top with a black background.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking to keep the image centered but the black background canvas (I think that's what photoshop would call it) to be expanded in all directions by the given amount, correct?

Comment: Your $pinky image should be created with the original width and height. You want your original image to become `$pinky_width` wide in the new one, _plus_ borders on each side - that obviously won't fit _into_ `$pinky_width`.

Comment: Thank you. This helps.  I ended up solving it for now with chatGPT, but I feel chatGPT took unnecessary steps and I am still not comprehending why it doesn't work.